# What's another word for "tails" when referring to distributions?

Tags: distributions

What's another word for "tails" when referring to the narrow ends of distributions?

Or is there another word for distribution tails?

It seems like I heard something else used before (e.g., x & y axes, abcissa & ordinate, or horizontal & vertical axes)

Comment: I don't know of another word for tails. Certainly none of the ones you've listed are synonyms for tails

Comment: maybe 'extremes'?

Comment: @PeterFlom I know the examples listed aren't related to distribution tails.  I was using them as examples of different names for the same thing or synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of "extreme values"? Or perhaps you're thinking of the business term "long tail" which is  based off the concept of a demand curve and might also be known by terms like "non-hit items", or refer to "low-volume" or "low-amplitude".